# Slow LAN speed 10 mbps instead of 100 mbps

Tags: networking, performance, lan, wired

I've just bought Mele Quieter 2 mini PC and faced the problem with low speed of "Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller" adapter. It always shows connection as 10 mbps:

[image]

What I've tried:

1. Reinstall/try different OS (including Linux) - same speed
2. Reinstall/update drivers of all kind
3. Switching cables/ports/routers of all kind
4. Forcing "100mbit full duplex" setting in windows and router
5. Search similar cases over internet and forums
6. Finally, I've asked manufacturer about that, waiting for response

Any thoughts how to fix this would be helpful

Comment: Do you have another PC you can test on the same cable?

Comment: Yes, I've tested multiple cables on multiple PCs